# Want to rotate element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to *rotate an element* (any element div,p..) with the *handle* (handle=>div) which I placed on the element's *top-left* corner, now my problem is that the element does not fully rotate to 360 degree, can anyone please help out :

```
$("#elementid").live('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).draggable({ handle: "#handleid", drag: function (event, ui) {
        var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + ui.position.left + 'deg)';
        alert(ui.position.left);
        $(this).parent().parent().css({
            '-moz-transform': rotateCSS,
            '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS
        });
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: 360 degree??? it will get its original position i think...

Comment: greate comment  @PriyankPatel is right but i think he meant to animate 360degree right

Comment: i means to say 0 degree to 360 degree ,only clever person can understand this :)

Comment: @KingKong what you meant from right to left rotation or clockwise rotation like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these are question in stackoverflow in the same category

**how to rotating div**

[trying to rotate a div element with jQuery controlling css3 transform command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382591/rotating-a-div-element-in-jquery)

[Rotating a Div Element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020904/how-to-rotate-a-div-using-jquery)

[How to rotate a div using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560683/trying-to-rotate-a-div-element-with-jquery-controlling-css3-transform-command)

take alook at the second link its briliant

[live rotate and other css demo brillian http://css3please.com/](http://css3please.com/)

**take a look at this to be precise**

```
.box_rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
     -moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
      -ms-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* IE9 */
       -o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
          transform: rotate(7.5deg);
             filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */
                     M11=0.9914448613738104, M12=-0.13052619222005157, M21=0.13052619222005157, M22=0.9914448613738104, sizingMethod='auto expand');
               zoom: 1;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

note this nice addition in middle of the page of [note this on http://css3please.com/](http://css3please.com/)

[image: you can manipulate what ever you want to generate code live]

Comment: Thanks for answer @shareef, but i want to know that, is there any scope in my code, by which, i can achieve what i want?

Comment: yes if i understand correctly you should add the .box_rotate class to the element you want to rotate like in this link example using addClass  and removeClass to the div,p or any element you wish : **Adds the specified class(es) to each of the set of matched elements.**
**.addClass( className )**
    classNameOne or more class names to be added to the class attribute of each matched element. [JQuery API .addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)  [JQuery API .removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate with Jquery rotate. Check fallowing example:

$(img).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');

$(img).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');

$(img).css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');

$(img).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');

$(img).css('transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');

You can also refer [CSS Matrix Rotation](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html)