# How can I rotate an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

Here is my code:

```js
$('.click').on('click', function(){
  $(this).next('div').toggle(100);
});
```

```css
.click{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="click">click  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
<div>something</div>
```

As you see that *arrow (which is next to `click`)* is fixed .. How can I rotate it 45° when user click on the `div.test` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to rotate element in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908760/want-to-rotate-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option: you can use fontawesome's `fa-caret-right` and toggle it!

Let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```js
$('.click').on('click', function(){
  $(this).next('div').toggle(100, 'linear', function(){
       $(this).prev('div').find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-down');
       $(this).prev('div').find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-right');
  });
});
```

```css
.click{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="click">click  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
<div>something</div>
```

Comment: I really don't understand why did you use `.prev()` in this case? What `.prev()` does exactly in there?

Comment: because inside the function `this` means `<div>something</div>`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `transform` CSS property. Read more about it in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

```js
$('.click').on('click', function(){
  $(this).next('div').toggle(100)
  $(this).children('i').toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

```css
.click{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="click">click  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
<div>something</div>
```